# How to connect 3 toggle switches to 1 battery supply, using 1 wire

Tags: batteries, wire, toggle-switch, protoboard, wire-terminals

I currently have a battery supply, 3 toggle switches, and a Protoboard.  The protoboard has various components connected to it, incluing two motors.  I need to connect two switches to the motor pins, and one to the board's power input.  Those connections have already been made.

However, I also need to connect the red wire (voltage out, 22 gauge) of the battery supply to one terminal on all 3 toggle switches.  This is where I am confused - how to connect one wire to 3 different switch terminals.

One thought was to strip the red battery wire, and then connect 3 new wires to the main red wire.  Another thought was to connect the red wire to one switch terminal, and then solder two wires to that terminal - and connect the other ends to the other switches.

Any ideas on what's appropriate here?  I don't want to 'fry' anything, so I'm hesitant to start testing things on my own.  Below is a brief visual of what needs to be done.  Thanks in advance!

[image]

Edit:

Thanks for the responses so far - I realize this is quite vague / confusing, mainly because I am very lost when it comes to hardwares/circuitry.

The overall goal is to allow the switches to toggle on/off the motors, and also toggle on/off the power supply to the CPU connected to the protoboard.  The purpose of this is to that I can test other functions of the protoboard/CPU, without running the motors - aka switching the motors 'on/off'.

The instructions I received go over this very briefly, and simply state "Connect the battery voltage (red wire) to one terminal of all 3 toggle switches.  Connect the other terminal of each switch to each motor, and to the main power supply."  The second part I have down - it's connecting the 1 battery wire to 3 separate switches that has me confused.

Comment: Why not have the protoboard do it?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve? What will you be able to do if it is all working? Why connect the two toggle switches to the motor? Are those toggle switches only off or on switches (as shown in your diagram)? Are you trying to control motor direction or something?

Comment: This question is something I would *really* love to help with, because it should be fairly simple, and because it would help you out. But it's missing a lot of information. What are the functions of the switches? Are you trying to have the switches turn on/off a motor, and control its direction or something?

Comment: Too vague to hazard a guess.

Comment: I've updated the question with a little more info (see Edit).  Thanks for any more input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the point in having the power toggle switch if you're just going to connect the battery +ve to the other toggle switches anyway...

It would make sense to me to have the red wire from the batteries going to the first 'power input' switch and then have another two wires coming out of the output from that switch to go to the other two switches, this way the power switch will actually turn everything off when you flick it and the motors will not run independently of this switch, which is, I am assuming, what you would want.

Here I have drawn a quick schematic of what I think you are looking for, if it's completely wrong, feel free to ignore me but this would make sense to me.
[image: Schematic of motor + switches]

So as you can see, the red wire from your batteries will go to the power switch which then in turn would go to the other two switches.
I personally would solder wires to SW2 and SW3 and then use the proto board to connect the three together, have the output of SW1 going to some hole in the board and then connect the other two to this point however you see fit! The less wiring the better.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is most likely the closest to what I'm wanting.  I will wait to see if there are any further answers/clarification, but otherwise will test this out tonight.  Using the protoboard to connect things together is where I'm a little lost - I've also updated my question a bit to describe what I'm wanting a little more.

Comment: @MidnightlyCoder is it breadboard type protoboard or board you have to solder to?

Comment: Unfortunately it's a board that needs to be soldered - a breadboard would allow for much easier testing.

Comment: @MidnightlyCoder Well in that case you can just solder the wire from the battery into the board and then solder the another three like single strand wires underneath the board from the power supply red wire to the terminals on the other switches. Alternatively you can do it all above the board, wiring three seperate wires from the batteries to the switches and have them flying around, that would be easier but less tidy.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look to try that tonight and will mark this as the answer afterwards if all works well.  I'm still a little new to how exactly boards work (meaning how to connect the switches from the board once the battery wire has been soldered to it) - but I think this should be enough for me to set everything up.

Comment: Something I've used on protoboard before is a wiring pen, good for making lots of connections underneath the board, I am assuming that all the solder points are not connected at all when I am giving this advice by the way! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If from your system follows that:

- the voltage is the same value for three: both motors and the board;
- independent switching all tree switches are proper for the system and its parts (all combinations of switched on/off between all three switches are acceptable)

then it simply is as follows:

[image]

Comment: That is exactly where I'm confused, how the V+ splits into 3 separate switches.  This diagram is exactly what I'm needing, it's just the actual split that I'm clueless on (the physical act of how to wire it).

Comment: Then you just split as the circuit shows: three separated wires, each goes from the red wire of the power supply to the "red-pin" of each switch.